# Combining an associative array with mysqli_fetch_assoc() php

Tags: php, arrays, mysqli, phpexcel, associative-array

I am using PHP Excel to create an excel document from data stored in the database. When it comes to displaying the data in a html table, it displays perfectly but when it comes to the excel file, I hit a road block. My code is as below:

```
$excelData = array(
        0 => array('Jackson','Barbara','27','F','Florida'),
        1 => array('Kimball','Andrew','25','M','Texas'),
        2 => array('Baker','John','28','M','Arkansas'),
        3 => array('Gamble','Edward','29','M','Virginia'),
        4 => array('Anderson','Kimberly','23','F','Tennessee'),
        5 => array('Houston','Franchine','25','F','Idaho'),
        6 => array('Franklin','Howard','24','M','California'),
        7 => array('Chen','Dan','26','M','Washington'),
        8 => array('Daniel','Carolyn','27','F','North Carolina'),
        9 => array('Englert','Grant','25','M','Delaware')
    );
```

I need the mysql data co create an array as the one above. so that I can use it in the piece of code below to display in the specific table cells.

```
for($i=0; $i<count($excelData); $i++){
        $ii = $i+3;
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('A'.$ii, $excelData[$i][0]);
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('B'.$ii, $excelData[$i][1]);
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('C'.$ii, $excelData[$i][2]);
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('D'.$ii, $excelData[$i][3]);
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('E'.$ii, $excelData[$i][4]);
}
```

My full code for the loop including my mysqli query is as below:

```
$qr = "SELECT * FROM ". DB_PROJECT_DETAILS_TBL ." WHERE project_id = '$project_id' ORDER BY id DESC";
    $mx = $db->runQuery($qr);

    // check for empty result
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($mx)) {
    $excelData = array(
        0 => array($row['col1'], $row['col2'], $row['col3'], $row['col4'], $row['col5'])
    );
}
```

Any assistance will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood correctly, you need replace this code

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($mx)) {
    $excelData = array(
        0 => array($row['col1'], $row['col2'], $row['col3'], $row['col4'], $row['col5'])
    );
}
```

With this code

```
$excelData = array();
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($mx)) {
    $excelData[] = array($row['col1'], $row['col2'], $row['col3'], $row['col4'], $row['col5']);
}
```

---

I also think you can use this snippet. I think it will decrease complexity a little bit

```
$qr = <<<SQL
    SELECT
    LIST ONLY NECESSARY COLUMNS
    FROM ". DB_PROJECT_DETAILS_TBL ." 
    WHERE project_id = '$project_id' 
    ORDER BY id DESC
SQL;
$mx = $db->runQuery($qr);
$excelData = mysqli_fetch_all($mx, MYSQLI_NUM);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->fromArray($excelData, null,'A3');
```

Comment: Why does everyone still use `$array = array();` this is 2018! `$excelData = [];`!!!

Comment: Indeed. Code above the line is just "fixing problem with minimal changes" edition